# Setting axis intervals in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, graphing

I have searched for this and can't believe I can't find it. Perhaps I've been asking the wrong question.

I have a set of data laid out in a histogram that has a xlim of $2,000,000. I am trying to set an interval of $100,000 for the breaks (rather than manually listing out every break with `break = c(0, 50000, 100000, etc)`. How can I do this in ggplot? The breaks (ticks) are more important than the labels as I'll likely edit in Illustrator an abbreviated label (100k, etc)

```
p <- ggplot(mcsim, aes(result))
+ scale_x_continuous(formatter = "dollar") 
+ geom_histogram(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + scale_y_continuous(formatter = 'percent')
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to set the bin width!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `breaks=seq(0, 2000000, by=100000)`.  Effectively you are using `seq` to generate that vector you don't want to type out by hand.